# Google OAuth Refresh Token Not Working With .Net Library (C# MVC Web App)

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

So I've been working with the Google API .net libray.. I've gotten it to work, and can successfully get the access token and refresh token, and use those to hit google API's.

I store both the access token and refresh token in my database for the user. And pull it out when im making calls. Which works fine, until the access token expires.

For reference here is the code that uses the refresh token from the database to make an api call:

```
            var t = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = GoogleOauthTokenService.getRefreshToken(User.Identity.Name) };
            var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "REDACTED",
                        ClientSecret = "REDACTED"
                    }
                }), User.Identity.Name, t);


            var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                ApplicationName = ""
            });
```

Looking at the library and googles docs, it should automatically use the refresh token to get another access token when expired.

This code works perfectly up until the access token eventually expires; At which case it gives an error "Invalid Grant: Token has been expired or revoked"

I've done a bit of research and the most common problems don't apply, which is why im stumped as to why this isnt working.

- Refresh Token is revoked or invalid, because too many were given out (I only ever grab 1 refresh token, unless the above call to the api is getting a new refresh token every call)
- Clock Time is out of sync (Checked, and system time is working and synced)